# Adding multiple owners for Google App Maker records

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I need help with Google App Maker data model security. I want to set multiple owners for a single record. Like the current user + the assigned admin + super admin.
I need this because all records can have different owners and super-owners/admins.
I know that we can point google app maker to a field containing record owner's email and we can set that field to the current user at the time of the creation of the record.

`record.Owner = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();`

I want to know if it is possible to have field owners or have multiple fields like owner1, owner2 and then assign access levels to owner1, owner2...

*Or how can we programmatically control the access/security/permissions of records?*

Comment: I only have a suggestion, this approach did not work a year ago but maybe it does now. Create a new model and call it ownership or something. Create one field of type string and call it owner. Then set a many-to-many relation between ownership and your model. In your model security do the advanced setting for all necessary events setting owner and then linking it to the related model field of owner. Second option is to use string to array and vice versa conversions and store all owners in a field in the model and store all owners as comma separated string.

Comment: Have you reviewed [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-app-data)?

Comment: Yes, @TheMaster and most relevant part from that is [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-app-data#record_owner).
I know that we can add permissions to roles on models but I need this on records.

Comment: Use *Script* based access? Check if record.owner or record.superOwner === activeUser, grant access?

Comment: One way would be to combine the role-based permissions for the entire model and make some [queries to filter the records](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I'd use for this one definitely involves a field on the record that contains a comma separated string of all the users who should have access to it. I've worked on the following example to explain better what I have in mind.

I created a model and is called **documents** and looks like this:

[image]

In a page, I have a table and a button to add new document records. The page looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the **Add Document** button, a dialog pops up and looks like this:

[image]

The logic on the **SUBMIT** button on the form above is the following:

```
widget.datasource.item.owners = app.user.email;
widget.datasource.createItem(function(){
  app.closeDialog();
});
```

That will automatically assign the creator of the record the ownership. To add additional owners, I do it on an edit form. The edit form popus up when I click the **edit** button inside the record row. It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I'm using a list widget to control who the owners are. For that, it is necessary to use a `<List>String` custom property in the edit dialog and that will be the datasource of the list widget. In this case, I've called it **owners**. I've applied the following to the **onClick** event of the edit button:

```
var owners = widget.datasource.item.owners;
owners = owners ? owners.split(",") : [];
app.pageFragments.documentEdit.properties.owners = owners;
app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.documentEdit);
```

The **add** button above the list widget has the following logic for the **onClick** event handler:

```
widget.root.properties.owners.push("");
```

The **TextBox** widget inside the row of the list widget has the following logic for the **onValueEdit** event handler:

```
widget.root.properties.owners[widget.parent.childIndex] = newValue;
```

And the **CLOSE** button has the following logic for the **onClick** event handler:

```
var owners = widget.root.properties.owners || [];
if(owners && owners.length){
  owners = owners.filter(function(owner){
    return owner != false; //jshint ignore:line
  });
}
widget.datasource.item.owners = owners.join();
app.closeDialog();
```

Since I want to create a logic that will load records only for authorized users, then I had to use a query script in the datasource that will serve that purpose. For that I created this function on a server script:

```
function getAuthorizedRecords(){
  var authorized = [];
  var userRoles = app.getActiveUserRoles();
  var allRecs = app.models.documents.newQuery().run();
  if(userRoles.indexOf(app.roles.Admins) > -1){
    return allRecs;
  } else {
    for(var r=0; r<allRecs.length; r++){
      var rec = allRecs[r];
      if(rec.owners && rec.owners.indexOf(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) > -1){
        authorized.push(rec);
      }
    }
    return authorized;
  }  
}
```

And then on the **documents** datasource, I added the following to the query script:

```
return getAuthorizedRecords();
```

[image]

This solution will load all records for admin users, but for non-admin users, it will only load records where their email is located in the **owners** field of the record. This is the most elegant solution I could come up with and I hope it serves your purpose.

References: 
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_script 
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties 
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/logic#events 
https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Record

Comment: Can you pls give me a hint how can we set different permissions for different data fields. Like some of the fields are visible to all the members of a role for viewing but admins and owners can view all fields and modify them. Thanks for you answer,

Comment: @NadeemGorsi It would seem that security settings based on individual fields are not possible at this time. The only way I can see to circumvent that is to set up those fields that need additional protection as a one-to-one relationship and then set your 'roles or owner' security setting on the related record.